# automate adding flexibility declaration with gulp

Tags: gulp, flexbox, flexibility

I want to add flexibility polyfill in my build to support ie8 & 9. Is there a way with gulp to add in the `-js-display: flex;` before `display: flex;` as required?

```
.container {
    -js-display: flex;
    display: flex;
}
```

https://github.com/10up/flexibility

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`gulp-postcss`](http://npmjs.com/package/gulp-postcss) in combination with the [`postcss-flexibility`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-flexibility) plugin:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var flexibility = require('postcss-flexibility');

gulp.task('css', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.css')
    .pipe(postcss([flexibility]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```